# How to do a Highchart who display usage / hours

Tags: meteor, highcharts

I'm trying do to a Highchart that display in real-time the memory usage of a container. I want to have on Y axe the memory usage (30M, 28M ...) and on the X axe the time when it was readed.

So in my collection I have 'read' who is the Unix time of when I readed the usage and 'memory_stats {usage}' who is the usage that I want to display.

Then my code to create the Highchart is :

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function() {
    data = [];
    var cursor = Template.currentData(),
        query = DockerStats.find(),
        initializing = true,
        liveChart;

    data = [];
    DockerStats.find().fetch().forEach(function(el) {
      var date = new Date(el.read*1000);
      // Hours part from the timestamp
      var hours = date.getHours();
      // Minutes part from the timestamp
      var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
      // Seconds part from the timestamp
      var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

      var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        data.push([time, el.memory_stats.usage]);
    });
    // Create basic line-chart:
    liveChart = Highcharts.chart(cursor.chart_id, {
        title: {
            text: 'Memory usage of the controlcontainers_mongo_1'
        },
        xAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'time reading'
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'usage'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'memory usage',
            data: data
        }]
    });

    // Add watchers:
    query.observe({
        added: function(addedThing) {
            if (!initializing) {
                var points = liveChart.series[0].points;
                // console.log(points)
                liveChart.series[0].addPoint([addedThing.memory_stats.usage]);
            }
        },
        removed: function(removedThing) {
            if (!initializing) {
                var points = liveChart.series[0].points;
                liveChart.series[0].addPoint([removedThing.memory_stats.usage]);
            }
        }
    });
    initializing = false;
});
```

But the chart is not how I wish :
[image]

Someone could help me to find what I'm doing wrong in the creation of my chart ?

Comment: In your live update area you are telling it just to add a point but defining no x value. So, it is treating it like a linear axis (0, 1, 2, etc). At the top of your code you are sending in a time stamp of 'hh:mm:ss' - which would be a category I think, because you have not told the xAxis to be datetime. What is your expected chart to look like?

Comment: Oh you advices were good now it's soon working as I want to. I just want to do something like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JKCLx/1/ but with data that are in my collection

Comment: Okay, then you need to make your xAxis use `datetime` and then when you send in the next new point you send it in as `[time, value]`. Right now your code to add the point is just sending in `[value]`.

Comment: THANK YOU ! It was that ! you can put the answer and I'll mark it